# Is There any Thread Spawn with Timeout?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I want to fork/run two threads, where each is supposed to do some work (say call a REST API). But, I want them to stop/interrupt when reaching some timeout threshold, if not returned yet.

Currently, I am using `tokio::spawn()` but still unable to produce such a code. Although any keyword would be appreciated, but a code snippet would be more valuable.

Comment: You probably want to add stop-after-timeout-period-expired logic into the thread itself, so that the thread voluntarily exits.  Stopping a thread externally means the thread won't have a chance to clean up any resources it might have allocated, which will likely lead to resource-leaks and/or deadlocks (if the thread had one or mutexes locked at the moment it stopped running)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner, right reasoning. I am thinking if something like tokio::timedout_spawn exists.

Comment: Can the task be made into an async function / future, or does it necessarily have to be a sync function run on a thread? If it can be made into a future then you can just wrap it in [`timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html).

Comment: @cdhowie, oh wow, I didn't expect that timeout would work with spawn as well. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Jaafar It will work but it won't abort the task once the timeout happens; the task will run to completion but the result will never be observed.

Comment: @cdhowie Only if the task has no yield points.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I assume by "work with spawn" he means e.g. `tokio::spawn()` or `spawn_blocking` both of which will run a task to completion regardless of whether the returned future is awaited and regardless of whether it yields.

Comment: @cdhowie Ah, I thought about the opposite: spawn a `timeout()`ed future.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh hmm, yeah I guess the comment is a big ambiguous.

Comment: @cdhowie, yep, I mean tokio::spawn() as indicated in the question, and thanks for weighing in. I think wrapping a spawn in a timeout is the solution, I will give it a try as soon as I have some time to.

Comment: @cdhowie, I am not sure I understand this statement _"It will work but it won't abort the task once the timeout happens; the task will run to completion but the result will never be observed"_. If I wrap it with timeout, and run spawn inside. What happens when the timeout hits (If the thread continues and the program has already continued working due to the spawn command)? In my case, I am anyway not observing the result. I am asynchronously checking it.

Comment: @Jaafar It would help me to explain what will happen if I could see your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use the select! macro. For more details, refer to the official [Rust Async Book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/03_select.html).

Answer (score 2):

If your tasks are asynchronous, you can simply wrap them in [`tokio::time::timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html) which will short-circuit evaluation of the `Future` if the time limit is elapsed:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::timeout;

async fn task_one() { /* do good work */ }
async fn task_two() { /* do good work */ }

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let timelimit = Duration::from_secs(5);
    tokio::spawn(timeout(timelimit, task_one()));
    tokio::spawn(timeout(timelimit, task_two()));
}
```

If you await the results, they will return `Result`s with `Ok(_)` if they completed within the allotted time or `Err(Elapsed)` if the limit was exceeded.

Keep in mind though that `Future`-cancellation only affects the direct execution of the cancelled `Future`, and will not cancel any indirect/spawned tasks. For example, if you reversed the calls above like this `timeout(timelimit, tokio::spawn(task_one()))`, then the timeout may exceed and you can no longer await the task, but it will continue in the background since you only cancelled the `JoinHandle` awaiting the *result* from the task.